# Ошибка с переменными в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
def pin():
    pinq = Tk()
    pinq.title('Enter pin')
    pinq.geometry('400x250')
    pinq['bg'] = 'cyan'
    pinw = '1196'
    inputq = '2'

    def qqww(): print(inputq)

    def add(n):
        inputq += n

    Button(pinq, command=qqww, text='More', bg='yellow').place(x=350, y=220)
    Button(pinq, command=lambda: add(1), text='1', width=5, height=3).place(x=10, y=10)
```

Почему функция `add` не видит переменную `inputq`, хотя `qqww` её видит?

Comment: add "видит" inputq, только изменить ее не вправе... объявите ее глобальной

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена!

Comment: @Jack_oS в данном случае nonlocal

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вложенная функция могла менять значение переменной внешней функции, нужно во вложенной функции объявить эту переменную как `nonlocal` ("нелокальную"):

```
def pin():
    ...
    inputq = '2'

    def qqww(): print(inputq)

    def add(n):
        nonlocal inputq
        inputq += n

    Button(pinq, command=qqww, text='More', bg='yellow').place(x=350, y=220)
    Button(pinq, command=lambda: add(1), text='1', width=5, height=3).place(x=10, y=10)
```